# samsung galaxy tab 7'' media query?

Tags: media-queries, galaxy-tab

this works for video, not for the images. do you know some better query?

```
@media (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (min-device-width: 600px)
and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want video, images, other media to behave responsively you will need to add in

```
video, embed, object, iframe, img {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also to ensure that your video sizes proportionally you should check out http://fitvidsjs.com/